# Student expelled in order to go undercover; his father heads the agency

Tags: story-identification, novella

Student cadet recruited to secret agency. Has to be expelled to go undercover. Turns out his father who he believed dead is the boss of the agency. Set in a future Earth society. Agency gets busted so our hero is left to fight on alone, heroically.
I have a large audiobook collection, and its in there somewhere

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You've tagged this "novella"; are you sure it's not a full novel?  When did you read this and where?  Was it in a magazine, or an Ace Double?  Note that the student recruited to go undercover is a bit tropey.

Comment: Also: "turns out his father is the boss of the agency" (though not necessarily always dead).

Comment: Some parts of this remind me of *The Puppet Masters* by Heinlein. In tht the MC is a secret agent, and we learn part way thru  the book that his boss is also his Father.  Bur he is an experienced agent, not a cadet, and is not expelled. Probably not a match, but the closest by RAH I think.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of The Puppet Masters too.

Comment: Puppet Masters is great, but not the one. It's set in the future so SF. I'm beginning to think I've merged more than one story. I have a large collection of audiobooks - it's in there somewhere

Comment: Ah, do you know approximately how far in the future? Like 2050 AD? 3000 AD? 2012 AD, but was published in 1990?

Comment: not so far in future. Maybe  a v few futuristic gadgets, but only to indicate it is the future. The student spots a logical flaw in what a teacher says, and refuses to back down faced with scorn of teacher and fellow students. Turns out this marks him out as a suitable recruit for the agency. This is how story begins